# Using return type polymorphism dictated by type classes

Tags: haskell, typeclass, return-type, adhoc-polymorphism, scoped-type-variables

I have a class `HasFavorite` which assigns certain domains with my corresponding favorites.

```
class HasFavorite domain where
    favorite :: domain

data Animal = Monkey | Donkey
    deriving Show
data Color = Red | Blue
    deriving Show

instance HasFavorite Animal where
    favorite = Donkey

instance HasFavorite Color where
    favorite = Blue
```

Now, I want to define this:

```
rant :: (Show d, HasFavorite d) => d -> String
rant x = (show x) ++ "sucks. " ++ (show (favorite :: d)) ++ " is better."
```

For every invocation of `rant x` there is a concrete type to which `favorite :: d` can be resolved. Why can't Haskell do this?

I have tried adding `{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}` but that did not help.

Comment: There's an annoying subtlety to `ScopedTypeVariables`, you have to add an explicit `forall` to the type signature. I think it will work if you change the type signature to `rant :: forall d. (Show d, HasFavorite d) => d -> String`.

Comment: Who would have guessed! In my defense, my question has more humor than the other question, though.

Comment: @AgnishomChattopadhyay It's a bit annoying, but with scoped type variables you inevitably need **some** way to distinguish whether an occurrence of a type variable is intended to be a reference to an existing variable or introducing a new one; the old standard Haskell way (of implicitly assuming all variable occurences are implicitly introduced at the beginning of the type expression) doesn't cut it anymore. Using explicit `forall` to introduce scoped variables is natural. I think having implicit variables keep their single-expression scope was to minimise breakage of existing code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to `ScopedTypeVariables`, you also need to add a `forall d` to the type signature of `rant`:

```
rant :: forall d. (Show d, HasFavorite d) => d -> String
rant x = (show x) ++ " sucks. " ++ (show (favorite :: d)) ++ " is better."
```

Or you could match on the argument type:

```
rant :: (Show d, HasFavorite d) => d -> String
rant (x :: d) = (show x) ++ " sucks. " ++ (show (favorite :: d)) ++ " is better."
```

See [the GHC manual](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/exts/scoped_type_variables.html) for all the details.

Comment: pretty sure this is a duplicate, this issue comes up a lot. I just put the same answer in a comment and was about to search for a suitable duplicate with which to close the question. (I had just found one but was too late, at least I am gratified that @DanielWagner chose the same duplicate as I was about to use!)